# Downloading and saving video into SD card does not show up (also not in Finder)

Tags: java, android, java-io

I have the following function `getWiFiFiles()` that receives video files from a device using WiFi and save them into SD card. The problem is that the files are not showing up in Samsung `My Files` app. After some search, I realised that it is not possible to show application private files so I took the SD card out of the Samsung device and put it into MacBook SD card reader. `Finder` in my macbook also unable to show downloaded files.

For further testing, I created java desktop application that uses the same function `getWiFiFiles()` and I could verify that function `getWiFiFiles()` downloads and saves the video files correctly.

Finally I checked permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` as I do have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

There is not error at all and I am not sure why file is not saved by the android device and it worked in my desktop application. Here is `getWiFiFiles()` code:

```
private void getWifiFiles(String strFile) {
    String filename = "";
    int fileSize = 0;
    String dataServerIp = "";
    int dataServerPort = 3001;

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    int bufferLength;
    Socket socket = null;

    boolean isFileSavable = false;
    String strAppDirectoryPath = "";

    String[] fileParams = strFile.split(",");
    if (fileParams.length >= 6) {
        filename = fileParams[4];
        fileSize = Integer.valueOf(fileParams[5]);
        dataServerIp = fileParams[2];
        dataServerPort = Integer.valueOf(fileParams[3]);
    }

    String[] serverIPs = dataServerIp.split(";");

    if (isThereSDCard()) {
        strAppDirectoryPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
        File appDirectoryPath = validateAndCreateAppDirecctory(strAppDirectoryPath);
        long freeBytesAppDir = appDirectoryPath.getFreeSpace();
        int freeAppDirMB = (int) (freeBytesAppDir / (1024 * 1024));

        if (freeAppDirMB >= (fileSize + 5)) {
            isFileSavable = true;
        } else {
            isFileSavable = false;
            wiFiFragment.showErrorPopup(context.getString(R.string.no_enough_storage));
            //ToDo: return downloadStatus
            downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NO_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE_IN_SD;
        }
    }
    if (!isFileSavable) {
        if (getFreeSpaceInPhoneMempry() >= (fileSize + 5)) {
            strAppDirectoryPath = context.getFilesDir().getPath();
            validateAndCreateAppDirecctory(strAppDirectoryPath);
            isFileSavable = true;
        } else {
            isFileSavable = false;
            //ToDo: return downloadStatus
            downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NO_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE_IN_INTERNAL;
            wiFiFragment.showErrorPopup("Your have no enough space to store this file");
            return;
        }
    }
    try {
        InetAddress serveraddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIPs[0]);
        socket = new Socket(serveraddr, dataServerPort);

        File file = new File(strAppDirectoryPath, filename);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        InputStream inputstram = socket.getInputStream();
        int totalSize = fileSize * 1024 * 1024;
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = inputstram.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            System.out.println("remaining: " + downloadedSize + " out of " + totalSize);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        socket.close();
        //ToDo: return downloadStatus
        downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.SUCCES;
        wiFiFragment.showErrorPopup("downliad finished");
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        //ToDo: return downloadStatus
        downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.FAILED;
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        wiFiFragment.showErrorPopup("Your Download Failed");
    }
}

private File validateAndCreateAppDirecctory( String strAppDirectoryPath) {
    File appDirectoryPath = new File(strAppDirectoryPath);
    if (!appDirectoryPath.exists()) {
        appDirectoryPath.mkdirs();
    }
    return appDirectoryPath;
}

private boolean isThereSDCard() {
    if (ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null).length >= 2) {
        File[] filename = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
            File file = filename[i];
            if (file != null && i == 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private int getFreeSpaceInPhoneMempry() {
    double availableSize = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();
    double freeMb = availableSize / (1024 * 1024);
    return Integer.valueOf((int) freeMb);
}
```

Here is the project data folder after reading the SD card by my Macbook:

[image: no_video_files_in_android_project_folder]

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to to with saving to a removable micro sd card. That check is useless.

Comment: isn't strAppDirectoryPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath(); saves into SD Card?

Comment: No. First that does not save. Second it is an app specific directory on external storage. Which is not removable micro sd card.

Comment: Then how to save? I am trying to save using FileOutputStream. I tested the code in java desktop application and it worked but it is not working in android environment.

Comment: Using FileOutputStream is ok. It is unclear to me what does not work.

Comment: 1. FileOutputStream is not saving the downloaded video into SD Card. I could not find the downloaded file, but I could find the downloaded folder with the package name (com.xxx.yyy).

Comment: You are not saving to removable micro sd card. I told you that before. Dont blame FileOutputStream. Blame using the wrong path.

Comment: Ok! What is the correct path then? By the way, I tried the same code but to save txt file and it was saved correctly in SD card in Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/hello_world.txt

Comment: The correct path would be getExternalFilesDirs()[1].getAbsoluthePath().